# Google Recaptcha always false

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, recaptcha

I have been following this short and sweet tutorial : [Integrating google recaptcha](http://recaptchamvc.apphb.com/)

I have made the relevant modifications to my view as shown here:

```
<div class="form-group" style="margin-left: 7%;">
  @Html.Recaptcha("MyKeyGoesHere", CaptchaTheme.Dark)
  @Html.ValidationMessage("ReCaptcha")
</div>
```

My controller looks like this:

```
  [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken()]
    [CaptchaValidator]
    public ActionResult SignUp(RegistrationSignUp model, bool captchaValid)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid) // Make sure all fields are field out.
        {
        }

      return View(model);
     }
```

But captchaValid is always false even though I have checked the check box? have I missed something? any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

```
var response = Request["g-recaptcha-response"];
if (response != null && ReCaptcha.IsValid(response))
{
        // 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get this working, by diving further into the complete documentation as shown here: [Complete integration guide for Google ReCaptcha](http://recaptchamvc.apphb.com/Home/Document)